# I am trying to add a UIPanGestureRecognizer to my uiimageview subclass but its not working

Tags: ios, uiimageview, subclass, uipangesturerecognizer

Here is my code, the first part is my custom subclass for the imageviews I want to instantiate 
The next section is the viewController.m viewdidload
I created the subclass so that each imageview would have its own uipangesturerecognizer instead of creating alot of different uipangesturerecognizers in the viewcontroller.h. I figured this was a more efficient and creative way of doing things but I can't seem to get the imageviews to move

Thanks for all the help in advance!

```
#import "blogsImageView.h"

@implementation blogsImageView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
   //custom imageview subclass
   self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
    NSLog(@"Test");
    [self setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
    [self setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panDetected:)];
    panRecognizer.delegate = self;

    [self addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
}
return self;
}

- (void) panDetected:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panRecognizer{

NSLog(@"Test");
if (panRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
{

}
else if (panRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
{
    CGPoint translation = [panRecognizer translationInView:self.superview];
    CGPoint imageViewPosition = self.center;
    imageViewPosition.x += translation.x;
    imageViewPosition.y += translation.y;

    self.center = imageViewPosition;
    [panRecognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView: self.superview];

}
else if (panRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
{

}

}

//my viewController file
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

blogsImageView *testImageView = (blogsImageView *)[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 300, 80, 80)];
[testImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"testImage"]];
[self.view addSubview:testImageView];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line,

```
blogsImageView *testImageView = (blogsImageView *)[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 300, 80, 80)];
```

is incorrect. Casting a UIView to a blogsImageView doesn't make it one. You need to alloc init your subclass,

```
blogsImageView *testImageView = [[blogsImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 300, 80, 80)];
```

Comment: Thanks that was exactly what I needed, Idk why i tired to cast it

Comment: @brianScroggins, you should accept my answer since it solved your problem.